# Xamarin.Forms Cross Mic Audio Streaming with AudioRecorder and CrossSimpleAudioPlayer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a simple PTT() Cross platform application with Xamarin.Forms. I have AudioRecorder.Plugin for recording and CrossSimpleAudioPlayer for playing the stream. I use nodejs and socket.io for the server part.

I send the recorded audio to the nodejs server every 5 secs. with the recorder.StartRecording() method.

```
buffer = new byte[recorder.GetAudioFileStream().Length];
await recorder.GetAudioFileStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
socket.Emit("AudioData", System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
```

Nodejs and socketio part seems pretty OK. cause i can see the data from the console log without any problem.

Below code is the playing part and it tries to convert data to stream and than plays.

```
socket.On("inboundData", (data) =>
{
    byte[] byts = Convert.FromBase64String(data.ToString());
    using (MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(byts))
    {
        var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;                       
        player.Load(strm);
        player.Play();
    }
});
```

But just before the playing part I get an  **(Java.IO.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1)** error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the entire java error stack?

Comment: There is more detail to the `IOException: Prepare failed` error... but i would "assume" that is it because the data that you are applying to the player is not understand (i.e. its format) or that is corrupt (i.e. it is not a fully formed sound sample).

Comment: @SushiHangover I cant able to add WAVE header to the stream.Normally I add WAVE header on the playing side.  When I try to do so , I get a  System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

Here is the code
                    AudioFunctions.WriteWavHeader(strm, 1, 11025, 16);

Comment: Maybe you should check the player status on the Current Player while doing this operation, there could be concurrency issues, multiple calls into this method perhaps may cause a problem like this... I've checked the GitHub for this project, Load() deletes the player and Prepares it again.